# Trying to populate a dropdown box from sql query in php

Tags: php, html

I need to populate a dropdown list based on the user's first dropdown selection, but before i even get that far I am just trying to populate one with a preselected team to make sure I get that part right first. However with this code I get my first dropdown with the team names, but then next to it is an empty text field and I can't seem to get the second dropdown to appear and populate. I am a newbie to html and php, I am fairly sure I'm missing something easy. Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if I can be more clear about my issue. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><style>
</style></head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="teams">
                    <option value="Atlanta Hawks ">Atlanta Hawks</option>
                    <option value="Boston Celtics ">Boston Celtics</option>
                    <option value="Charlotte Bobcats ">Charlotte Bobcats</option>
                    <option value="Chicago Bulls ">Chicago Bulls</option>
                    <option value="Cleveland Cavaliers ">Cleveland Cavaliers</option>
                    <option value="Dallas Mavericks ">Dallas Mavericks</option>
                    <option value="Denver Nuggets">Denver Nuggets</option>
                    <option value="Detroit Pistons ">Detroit Pistons</option>
                    <option value="Golden State Warriors">Golden State Warriors</option>
                    <option value="Houston Rockets ">Houston Rockets </option>
                    <option value="Indiana Pacers ">Indiana Pacers </option>
                    <option value="LA Clippers ">LA Clippers</option>
                    <option value="LA Lakers ">LA Lakers</option>
                    <option value="Memphis Grizzlies ">Memphis Grizzlies</option>
                    <option value="Miami Heat">Miami Heat</option>
                    <option value="Milwaukee Bucks ">Milwaukee Bucks</option>
                    <option value="Minnesota Timberwolves ">Minnesota Timberwolves</option>
                    <option value="New Jersey Nets">New Jersey Nets</option>
                    <option value="New Orleans Hornets ">New Orleans Hornets</option>
                    <option value="New York Knicks ">New York Knicks</option>
                    <option value="Oklahoma City Thunder ">Oklahoma City Thunder</option>
                    <option value="Orlando Magic ">Orlando Magic</option>
                    <option value="Philadelphia Sixers ">Philadelphia Sixers </option>
                    <option value="Phoenix Suns ">Phoenix Suns</option>
                    <option value="Portland Trail Blazers ">Portland Trail Blazers</option>
                    <option value="Sacramento Kings ">Sacramento Kings</option>
                    <option value="San Antonio Spurs ">San Antonio Spurs</option>
                    <option value="Toronto Raptors ">Toronto Raptors</option>
                    <option value="Utah Jazz">Utah Jazz</option>
                    <option value="Washington Wizards ">Washington Wizards</option>


</select>
<input type="text" name="team">
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","nbastakm_josh","ateam","nbastakm_Stats"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname FROM PlayerRegSeason WHERE team='NYK' and year='2009'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
}
$playermenu = "
<p><label>Players</label></p>
<select name='players' id='players'>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$playermenu = "<option>".$row['lname']."</option>";
}
$playermenu = "</select>";
echo $playermenu;
mysqli_close($con);

?>

</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the next dropdown must be ajax loaded using the country id from the fist dropdown. This is called: interdependent dropdowns and you can find more information here: https://www.google.ro/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=interdependent+dropdowns&spell=1

Answer (score 0):

Use dot to concatenate strings:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $playermenu .= "<option>".$row['lname']."</option>";
}
$playermenu .= "</select>";
```

Comment: This gives me a syntax error after the while statement saying unexpected = . When i remove that . I have the same empty text field.

Comment: Really strange. Can you create a PhpFiddle with your updated code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with phpfiddle and I may be glancing over it, but I don't see a place to enter code, just to create code.                  Edit: I found where to enter my code, but not sure how to create a phpfiddle. when i run it i get the same problems.

Comment: Are there news on this?

Answer (score 0):

it isn't possible to use client option without resending to server. you need:

- ajax,
- a second page (step 2 in wizard) were you can check the "teams" or
- you can reload page with javascript after changing teams

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean step 2 in wizard? I have been doing everything from scratch.